# What's the best way to validate a user-entered URL in a Cocoa application?

Tags: regex, cocoa, validation, url

I am trying to build a homebrew web brower to get more proficient at Cocoa. I need a good way to validate whether the user has entered a valid URL. I have tried some regular expressions but NSString has some interesting quirks and doesn't like some of the back-quoting that most regular expressions I've seen use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could start with the [`+ (id)URLWithString:(NSString *)URLString`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/URLWithString:) method of [`NSURL`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/URLWithString:), which returns `nil` if the string is malformed.

If you need further validation, you can use the `baseURL`, `host`, `parameterString`, `path`, etc methods to give you particular components of the URL, which you can then evaluate in whatever way you see fit.

Comment: For anyone confused by this: NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"test"]; if(myURL){ } is not enough because "test" is a valid URL. You probably will want to add use:     if (myURL && myURL.scheme && myURL.host) { }

Comment: if (myURL && myURL.scheme && myURL.host) { } this will not work. It will be still valid for ULR like "xxxx://xxxx://www.googl.com"

Answer (score 4):

I've found that it is possible to enter some URLs that seem to be OK but are rejected by the NSURL creation methods.  So we have a method to escape the string first to make sure it's in a good format.  Here is the meat of it:

```
NSString *escapedURLString =
    NSMakeCollectable(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
      (CFStringRef)URLString,
      (CFStringRef)@"%+#",  // Characters to leave unescaped
      NULL,
      kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
```