# Check whether NSURLConnection not success in  iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5, nsurlconnection

```
-(void)loadRequest:(NSString *)jsonString{
receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
urlString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:kURL]];
urlRequest=[NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   requestInformation =[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:urlRequest cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
[requestInformation setValue:khttpValue forHTTPHeaderField:kContentType];
[requestInformation setValue:@"value1" forHTTPHeaderField:@"key1"];

[requestInformation setHTTPMethod:kPost];
jsonData= [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"json=%@",jsonString] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[requestInformation setHTTPBody:jsonData];

connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:requestInformation delegate:self];
[connection start];
if(connection){
    NSLog(@"Connection succesfull");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"There is a error in connection");
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(onFailedToUpload) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}
}
```

how to check if the else part is executed. I give incorrect URL , didfailwitherror method is called but the else part is not executed.

Comment: If you want to handle bad URLs, then do the checking on the URL, not the connection. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471201/how-to-validate-an-url-on-the-iphone ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192944/whats-the-best-way-to-validate-a-user-entered-url-in-a-cocoa-application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the `connection` object is always created. Even of your url is wrong. Any errors whatsoever comes to the delegate `didFailWithError` method. You probably need to examine the error & proceed appropriately. Ex. In case it is a timeout you might want to retry in `didFailWithError` delegate. For other error types handle differently.

If you want to handle broken or bad urls before passing it to `NSURLConnection` then you need to do that yourself.

Here are the delegates which are of use to you when using `NSURLConnection` -

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
{
    NSLog("@Resp received");
    return;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    didReceiveData:(NSData *)data 
{
    NSLog("@Data received");
    return
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
    NSLog("@ERROR: Achtung !: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH , 0),, ^{
        NSLog(@"FinishedLoading: In bg thread, do something with data here");

        dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"FinishedLoading: In Main thread, access the UI here");
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply